# Can't run WCF service application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create my first WCF service application, but I can't get it to run from Visual Studio 2015.

This is the error I get when I click run...

[image]

I was following a tutorial and I think they skipped a few steps, but here's what I added to the web.config

```
<services>
  <service name="OnPatrolRest.Service1">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:51964/service1"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="OnPatrolRest.IService1"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

and here's the Interface

```
    <ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/getPerson?id={id}")>
    Function getPerson(ByVal id As String) As Person

End Interface
```

and for the class file...

```
Public Function getPerson(ByVal id As String) As Person Implements IService1.getPerson
        Dim p As New Person

        p.Id = Convert.ToInt32(id)
        p.Name = "Sterling Archer"

        Return p
    End Function
```

That's the only function I added. What am I missing. I'm very new to this. Every post I've seen is from years ago and doesn't work in VS 2015.

Thank you very much for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, in a Console app. No `Web.config` or `App.config` necessary.

**Main module**

```
Module Main
  Sub Main()
    With New Manager(GetType(Service), "SomeService", 8080)
      Environment.ExitCode = .StartService
    End With
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Service manager**

```
Friend Class Manager
  Implements ServiceControl

  Public Sub New(ServiceType As Type, ServiceName as String, WcfPort As Integer)
    Me.ServiceType = ServiceType
    Me.ServiceName = ServiceName
    Me.WcfPort = WcfPort
  End Sub



  Public Sub StartService
    Try
      Me.OpenServiceHost()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
  End Sub



  Public Sub StopService
    Try
      Me.CloseServiceHost()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
  End Sub



  Public Sub OpenServiceHost()
    Me.ServiceHost.Open()
  End Sub



  Public Sub CloseServiceHost()
    If Me.ServiceHost.IsNotNothing Then
      If Me.ServiceHost.State <> CommunicationState.Closed Then
        Me.ServiceHost.Close()
      End If
    End If
  End Sub



  Private ReadOnly Property ServiceHost As ServiceHost
    Get
      If _ServiceHost Is Nothing Then
        _ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(Me.ServiceType, Me.ListenerAddress)
        _ServiceHost.AddDefaultEndpoints()
      End If

      Return _ServiceHost
    End Get
  End Property
  Private _ServiceHost As ServiceHost



  Private ReadOnly Property ListenerAddress As Uri
    Get
      Return New Uri($"http://{Environment.MachineName}:{Me.WcfPort}/{Me.ServiceName}")
    End Get
  End Property



  Private Property ServiceName As String
  Private Property WcfPort As Integer
End Class
```

**Service Interface**

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IService
  <OperationContract> Function GetFilteredResult(Workstations As List(Of String), ProcessName As String) As Result
  <OperationContract> Function GetResult(Workstations As List(Of String)) As Result
End Interface
```

**Service implementation**

```
Public Class Service
  Implements IService

  Public Function GetFilteredResult(Workstations As List(Of String), ProcessName As String) As Result Implements IService.GetFilteredResult
    '
    ' Code goes here
    '
  End Function



  Public Function GetResult(Workstations As List(Of String)) As Result Implements IService.GetResult
    '
    ' Code goes here
    '
  End Function
End Class
```

I usually pair these with TopShelf; the combination provides a nice self-hosted WCF Service wrapped in a Windows Service.