# How can I make sure that my program can always be running and if the computer restarts or the process dies it can start again automatically?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a program that needs to be running on a server all the time. The idea would be that if at any time the server is restarted or for any reason the program is closed, it can be started again automatically.

The server has a windows 10 installer and in order to start it automatically I have put it in the startup programs but would there be any way that if you close the program manually or kill the process it could start again automatically?

The program is a windows form developed in vb.net; would it be necessary to add something to the project or would it be necessary to touch in the windows services?

Thank you and forgive me if my English is not perfect, it is not my native language

The functionality of the program consists in that when a file is introduced in a certain directory, it jumps the event and treats it making a series of changes, adds it to a database and then changes the directory. Due to this functionality I have to keep it always running and never stop

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a windows service: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: If your app has a GUI then you can't make it a Windows service but you can certainly create a Windows service that will check that whether the GUI app is running and, if not, start it. Windows services can be stopped too but you can use Windows security to prevent users doing that if they should be able to. It is now over to you to research those things.

Comment: A watchdog program could help. It can check if the software is running and, if not, start it.
you want to keep it simple so it has no reason to hang, but you could add simple features like checking if the main program has hung and terminate/restart if necessary.

Comment: Could you write the program without a GUI? That would be the simplest way to be able to make it into a Windows Service. If it uses a GUI for something like showing activity, that could be written to a log file instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Services is your bet. You can build a companion service, and use them both to keep an eye on each other to make sure they're both always running.

The easiest way to build a Windows Service is with [TopShelf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/). If your app needs a GUI you can build a self-hosted WCF Service into your Windows Service and make the GUI your WCF Client.

Here's a simple example showing [how to self-host your WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908500/722393).

Answer (score 3):

As others write, the best way to go on a server is a windows service for the program and some additional "watchdog" companion service (2 instances of those) to keep an eye on each other and on the main program.

However, if you want to stay with the windows forms program you have, there is another quite simple way:

- Use the windows task scheduler (type taskschd.msc in the start menu).
- Configure the program to run under some user account. The user does not need to be logged on, but if you want to see the UI then better to have him logged on.
- On one of the config tabs there is a setting to not start a new instance of the programm if it is already running.
- Let the task run once a minute, indefinitelly (set in the trigger configuration). You can have it run more often than once a minute, but that requires exporting the task config, editing it manually and than reimporting it again.

Good luck!